# C scanf not working as intended (Help!)

Tags: c, string-formatting

Was working on a program that prompts a user to enter a phone number and than prints it out using . instead of - so and when I run it it doesn't even let me input anything it just runs and gives me random values. So here's a look at the full program.

```
int item_number, year, month, day, first, middle, last;
//float unit_price;

printf("Enter item number: ");
scanf("%d", &item_number);

printf("Enter unit price: ");
scanf("%f", &unit_price);

printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
scanf("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year);

printf("Item\t\tUnit\t\tPurchase\n\t\tPrice\t\tDate");
printf("\n%d\t\t$%6.2f\t\t%.2d/%.2d/%.2d\n", item_number, unit_price, month, day, year);

//here is the code that gives me the problem explained above.
//also if i comment the code above it works.
printf("Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx] : ");
scanf("(%d) %d - %d", &first, &middle, &last);

printf("You entered %d.%d.%d", first, middle, last);
```

Comment: `scanf("(%d) %d - %d",` --> `scanf(" (%d) %d - %d",`

Comment: The phone number handling code is good; your error must be elsewhere.  If you really aren't even getting the chance to input numbers, the problem is probably in the way your program is being invoked--somehow stdin is not being connected to your terminal.  Could you be redirecting input (either through a pipe or by invoking with `< /some/file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have encountered, is probably one of the most common problems encountered by new C programmers -- the improper use of `scanf`. Specifically, when you attempt to read the telephone number, `stdin` contains, e.g.:

```
    "\n(888) 555-1212"
```

(the `'\n'` the result of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `(mm/dd/yyyy)` is entered)

As a result, the input waiting in `stdin` does **not** match `"(%d..."`, and a *matching failure* results. Why? There is a *newline* at the beginning of the characters in `stdin`. The `"%d"` *format specifier* (all numeric *conversion specifiers*) will skip leading whitespace.

However, *the leading whitespace does not precede the integer*, it precedes the `"("` which is not skipped by your *format string*. With `scanf`, a `" "` (*space*) in the *format string*, will cause any number of whitespace characters to be skipped/discarded. So as BLUEPIXY correctly notes, you need to add the *space* before the `"("` in the *format string* to have `scanf` ignore the `'\n'` waiting in `stdin`.

Beyond that, you make the same mistake and misuse of `scanf` that nearly all new C-programmers do -- *failing to check the* ***return***. `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions that take place based on the *conversion specifiers* in the *format string*.

At minimum, you must check the return of `scanf` (and in fact on ALL USER INPUT functions) to provide minimal validation that you do in fact have valid input stored in your variables to proceed forward with in your code. If you fail to check the return, you can have no confidence that undefined behavior isn't being invoked from that point forward. So *validate all user input*.

A minimal rewrite of your code that puts those pieces together would be:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main (void) {

    int item_number, year, month, day, first, middle, last;
    float unit_price;

    printf("Enter item number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &item_number) != 1) {  /* validate item */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (item_number)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter unit price: ");
    if (scanf ("%f", &unit_price) != 1) {   /* validate unit */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (unit_price)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    /* validate date */
    if (scanf ("%d /%d /%d", &month, &day, &year) != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (mm/dd/yyyy)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\t\tUnit\t\tPurchase\nItem\t\tPrice\t\tDate");
    printf ("\n%d\t\t$%6.2f\t\t%.2d/%.2d/%.2d\n", 
            item_number, unit_price, month, day, year);

    printf ("Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx] : ");
    /* validate phone */
    if (scanf (" (%d) %d - %d", &first, &middle, &last) != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("You entered %d.%d.%d\n", first, middle, last);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_phone
Enter item number: 3
Enter unit price: 19.95
Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): 03/01/2017
                Unit            Purchase
Item            Price           Date
3               $ 19.95         03/01/2017
Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx] : (800) 555-1212
You entered 800.555.1212
```

(**note** I tweaked the format to put `Item` on the 2nd line...)

Look things over, and spend the time it takes to understand [**man 3 scanf**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). It is time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are  using Xcode, then write your printf statements like so:

```
printf("Enter item number:\n");
```

Put a newline(\n) at the end.

Comment: Not absolutely necessary; you can use `fflush(stdout);` instead.  Also, I don't believe this is the main problem.